# Ajax to C# controller: How to pass an Array of objects along with other data

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have the following code:

**Class:**

```
public class EngineGroup
{      
    public string CategoryName { get; set; }  
    public OemPart[] ArrOemParts { get; set; }

}

public class OemPart {
    public string IdInDiagram { get; set; }
    public string Sku { get; set; }
    public string OemName { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
 public IActionResult Insert(EngineGroup eg){

 }
```

**JavaScript:**

```
            var formData = new FormData();     
            formData.append("CategoryName", groupEngineName);     
            formData.append("ArrOemParts", arrOemParts); // --  >>> this is an array of objects

 $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            data: formData,
            url: "/Insert",
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
```

When I am sending the FormData to the controller, the array of objects is empty while the rest of the data is successfully passed to the controller.
I was trying to do `JSON.stringify(formData)` with no luck...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 public class OemPart {
        public string IdInDiagram { get; set; }
        public string Sku { get; set; }
        public string OemName { get; set; }
    } 

[HttpPost]
        [IgnoreAntiforgeryToken(Order = 2000)]
        public IActionResult InsertCategoryAndOemPart([FromBody] OemPart[] oemPart, string categoryName)
        {
```

---

```
 $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            data: JSON.stringify(arrOemParts),
            url: "/admin/engineGroup/InsertCategoryAndOemPart/?categoryName=" + categoryName 
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
```